# Random integers, calculations, and tables

Tags: python, loops, tabular

> Write a program that displays a table of distance equivalents in miles and kilometers. You must generate the table by running a function inside a loop in main. Generate a random integer from 10 to 60, inclusive, in each loop cycle. Use this latter value as the miles argument to the function. The function must then print a line in the table. Repeat: The function prints the table.

I am able to get the top part of the table to print correctly. When I run my code at the top it gives me the calculation for the kilometers only for one number, and then just prints the same number 10 times for the kilometers and the random integers for the mileage. How do I get it to print out the 10 random numbers for the miles and the calculations in the right spot for the kilometers.

Here is my code:

```
import random
def main():
    print('Miles\tKilometers')
    miles = random.randrange(10, 60)
    find_kilometers(miles)

for value in range(10):
   miles = random.randrange(10, 60)
   print(format(miles, '.2f'))


def find_kilometers(miles):
   kilometers = miles * 1.60934
   for kilo in range(10):
   print(format(kilometers, '.5f'))



 main()
```

Answer (score 2):

Move the loop into `main`, and make `find_kilometers` return a value instead of printing it. Then you can easily print both values.

```
import random
def main():
    print('Miles\tKilometers')
    for value in range(10):
        miles = random.randrange(10, 60)
        print(format(miles, '.2f'), find_kilometers(miles), sep='\t')

def find_kilometers(miles):
   kilometers = miles * 1.60934
   return format(kilometers, '.5f')

main()
```

Sample:

```
Miles   Kilometers
24.00   38.62416
31.00   49.88954
14.00   22.53076
20.00   32.18680
24.00   38.62416
33.00   53.10822
20.00   32.18680
26.00   41.84284
49.00   78.85766
51.00   82.07634
```